# Can't configure varnish to work with cookies and drupal module

Tags: drupal-7, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using cookies so that mobile users can visit my site as desktop users.  To do this, I give them a cookie - mob_yes.

Then, in a module, i use a drupal hook to see if the cookie is set.

I can see that the cookie IS getting set, but in my module (isset($_COOKIE["mob_yes"])) always returns false when using varnish.

In /etc/varnish/default.vlc I have the following:

```
if (req.http.Cookie) {
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(mob_yes)=", "; \1=");
```

I'm really not sure what's going on here, but I only presume varnish is not unsetting that cookie temporarily?  Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to specify where is located your pasted code. Does it belongs to vcl_recv, vcl_hash, vcl_hit or vcl_fetch ?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by

> I can see that the cookie IS getting set

you mean that you can see it in headers in firebug (client side) and then you see it on the server side with tcpdump / varnishlog / application (server side)?

code snippet from vcl is probably part of commonly used way of preserving important cookies by adding a space in front of them, deleting all that dont have ";[space]" combination and removing space at the end.
It is used later on to generate hash for specific url+cookies request.

i think you should check your vcl if its not removing any cookies if user is not logged in - it's a common practice to increase hitrate.

usually in vcl for drupal it's part which checks for DRUPAL_UID